Changing the log driver in /etc/docker/daemon.json has no effect
I currently have the following log driver configured in /etc/docker/daemon.json:
{
    "log-driver": "journald",
    "log-opts": {
        "tag": "{{.Name}}"
    },
    "userland-proxy": false
}

It works, logs are sent to systemd-journald.
I tested sending logs from some containers via GELF and it works great as well:
    logging:
      driver: "gelf"
      options: 
        gelf-address: "udp://192.168.10.2:12201"
        tag: "caddy"

So far so good.
I then wanted to make a global change and have all the logs from all containers go to the log receptacle (via GELF), so I replaced my /etc/docker/daemon.json with
{
    "log-driver": "gelf",
    "log-opts": {
        "gelf-address": "udp://192.168.10.2:12201",
        "tag": "{{.Name}}"
    },
    "userland-proxy": false
}

After restarting dockerd there are no changes: the logs go to systemd-journald and the ones I configured at the docker-compose.yml level are sent via GELF.
In other words, changing /etc/docker/daemon.json and restarting dockerd had no effects. Have I missed something?
dockerd is started as
root@srv /e/docker# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-04-18 14:13:13 CEST; 21h ago
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
   Main PID: 869846 (dockerd)
      Tasks: 51
     Memory: 212.3M (peak: 269.1M)
        CPU: 6min 819ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             └─869846 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock


Docs say this. “Changing the default logging driver or logging driver options in the daemon configuration only affects containers that are created after the configuration is changed.”—How is it, did you recreate all containers?

@DanielB: no I did not, and recreating them indeed solves the issue. Would you mind turning your comment into an answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

In the Docker engine documentation about configuring logging drivers, there’s a note:

Changing the default logging driver or logging driver options in the daemon configuration only affects containers that are created after the configuration is changed. Existing containers retain the logging driver options that were used when they were created. To update the logging driver for a container, the container has to be re-created with the desired options.

It would appear that the logging driver is an immutable container property that can only be changed by creating a new container. What’s in daemon.json is merely the default for new containers.
Further down on the page, there’s also a command that can be used to quickly identify a container’s current logging driver:
docker inspect -f '{{.HostConfig.LogConfig.Type}}' CONTAINER

If you have any existing containers (as listed by docker ps -a), you must stop, remove and then recreate them to have the change take effect.
